# What is usually understood as DOMAIN and CODOMAIN of a Relation

Tags: notation, relations

Suppose I have a relation declaration as $R \subseteq A \times B$, such that $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B=\{10,20,30,40\}$.

And suppose that the definition of this relation is $R=\{(1,20),(3,40)\}$

- We call A Domain of $R$.
- We call B Co-domain of $R$.

How we refer to the subset of $A$ and $B$ that are related by $R$; that is, how we refer to sets $\{1,3\}$ and $\{20,40\}$.

**Update:**
I think, the above question  comes from the fact that usually there is not clear distinction between a relation declaration (that is a type) and a concrete relation (that is an occurrence of that type). $R \subseteq A \times B$ is a type declaration and $R=\{(1,20),(3,40)\}$ is an instance of it. So it is better to call the former $R$ and the latter $r_1$ (considering that there might be other relations like $r_2, r_3, ...$ typed over the same $R$. But even with such a distinction, what is meant by Domain /Codomain when they are used for $r_1$?

Comment: Domain of $R=\{1,3\}$ and range of $R=\{20,40\}$ co-domain of $R=\{10,20,30,40\}$

Comment: I think this is a matter of choice of terminology. I'd usually call the domain $A$, the co-domain $B$ and the other things are the projections of $R$ onto $A$ and $B$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28relational_algebra%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various conventions regarding the nomenclature for relations. Unfortunately, they are often conflicting.

On the one hand, we have the "axiomatic-set-theoretic" names:

- $A, B$ have no name
- $\{1,3\} = \{x \mid \exists y: (x,y)\in R\}$ is called the *domain* of $R$
- $\{20,40\} = \{y \mid \exists x: (x,y)\in R\}$ is called the *codomain* of $R$

On the other hand, we have (for lack of a better name) the "naive-set-theoretic" names:

- $A$ is the *domain* of $R$
- $B$ is the *codomain* of $R$
- $\{1,3\} = \{x \mid \exists y: (x,y)\in R\}$ is called the *preimage* of $R$
- $\{20,40\} = \{y \mid \exists x: (x,y)\in R\}$ is called the *image* of $R$

The *image* in the latter sense is often called the *range*; this is something both conventions agree on. Both conventions also seem to agree on the meaning of *preimage* and *image*.

But whenever one is consulting a source, care needs to be taken in the interpretation of these terms, so as to avoid confusion and mistakes.

Comment: What, then, is the _range_ of $R$, both for the "axiomatic-set-theoretic" and "naive-set-theoretic" names?