# Older textbook, definitions incoherent with contemporary theory

Tags: functions, definition

I have an Italian textbook from 1988 (Nicola Fedele), I encountered a definition of codomain incoherent with the contemporary one.
It defines the codomain as:

> To denote a function f of set X ⊆ S in T, the following notation is
>   used:
>     f : X ⊆  S → T
>   ...
>   The set X is named *definition set* or also *domain* of the function f; while the subset of T composed of the elements in relation to the elements of X thru the function f is named *values set* or also *codomain* of the function f, and is denoted with the symbol f(X).

Here the codomain is defined as what modern math defines as image.

I wasn't expecting such an inconsistency from a 1988 textbook, as I'm also reading a textbook from 1994 which presents the "correct" definition.
My question is, if inferrable, if it is plausible that I'll encounter several other quirks from this textbook, and I should rather purchase a different one, or if it's likely that this is a rare exception and I can turn a blind eye at it. My objective is to learn contemporary math, I'm not interested in older theories.

Comment: Without taking a position on whether the use of terminology here is reasonable, I think it bears pointing out that the context seems to be that of a *partial function* $f$ defined only on a subset $X$ of $S$.  So not only the meaning of *codomain* but the meaning of *domain* of a function might be the intended target of specialized definitions.

Comment: This seems to be the generic definition of function. Regardless, under a contemporary interpretation, wouldn't the notation be incoherent with the definition? The set right of the arrow should be defined as domain, not as a superset of the domain. This seems to be an [obsolete convention](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1374427/579326), and I'm worried about encountering more.

Comment: When I rode a dinosaur to school, the image was the set of things that got hit and the range was a superset of the image. At some point after that, the term codomain came into use, but not consistently. Some refer to it as the range and some as the image. I gather that the standard meaning now is that the codomain is the range, but it's perfectly possibly that this is not universally agreed on. No need to toss a book just because it uses a nonstandard def. Just use the terminology they use. Plenty of things in math have slightly different definitions in different texts.

Comment: Now I see that this textbook defines a biunivocal function as a synonym of injective function, while conventionally the two are defined differently. I'm worried whether I'll risk going on this route.

Comment: The text you quote has various errors in English, in English mathematical terminology, and in mathematical notation. Is it reproduced verbatim from the book; is it transcribed manually from the author's English text; or is it your translation of the original Italian text?

Comment: @JohnBentin, I'll assume your intention is to provide guidance. The text is my translation; how would you correct it with the smallest possible alteration? I suppose you can post an answer if a comment is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not be scared by terms used unconventionally as long as those terms are unambiguously defined by the Author. Yes, today *codomain* is a term that all agree to define in the same ways, but still some 30 years ago in non-English speaking countries *codomain* could be defined as the *image* or as the *target set* depending on author's preference. The same kind of ambiguity that today still persists for *range* in English speaking countries.

As to *biunivocal* that you say in a comment, it is not really clear what you mean, because this term is not very much used internationally in math. Probably you mean *one-to-one*. Note that a *one-to-one function* is said an *injective function*, while a function that is *one-to-one corrispondence* is said a *bijective function*. So be warned about such a subtlety. In Italian *one-to-one* is not usually translated word by word, rather it is translated with a word that indeed resemble "biunivocal", but there is no difference between a "biunivocal" function and a function that is a "biunivocal" corrispondence in Italian, they both mean *bijective function*. So stick to *injective* and *bijective* terms, that have no translation problems.

But again this is not important, as long as a definition is given with no ambiguity. If you deeply learn concepts, you will not feel uneasy changing terminology when a new context occurs.

Furthermore, with the notation:
$$f\colon X\subseteq S\to T$$
the Author says what he means, that is, he defines it unambiguously (reread the definition, if not clear).

I've never read Nicola Fedele, but I know that he is an authority, pupil of [Federico Cafiero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federico_Cafiero). So I would not discard his book (still in widespread use) just for the unconventional terminology.

Just as an example Herstein in his beautiful "Topics in Algebra" second edition 1975 had been using *isomorphism into* and *isomorphism onto* instead of the now common *monomorphism* and *isomorphism*, respectively. But this is a book that still is worth reading, even though at the beginning one feels uneasy because of that: at least it helps you to develop a critical approach when reading math in terms of paying the utmost attention to every single word.

Answer (score 0):

Analysis of the posted text is complicated by it being a faulty translation from the original Italian. However, some features appear to be a fair representation of the author's writing, and some of those are nonstandard. The notation $f : X ⊆ S → T$ is nonstandard. We would normally write $f : X → T$, with  $X ⊆ S$ either being obvious from the context or stated separately. In English, $f(X)$ is called the *range* (or *image*, in some contexts) of $f$, and $T$ is the *codomain*. Calling the range "codomain" is simply contrary to normal usage. The term *domain* is correctly used, but *definition set* has little currency in English. The term *value set* (or the grammatically incorrect form *values set*) is also unconventional in English.

In mathematical writing, some unconventiality may improve on the standard form, or may be justified by the particular context; but generally it makes life harder for readers—and for students in particular. It's difficult to assess whether this author's terminological creativity will cause real problems of understanding for you. While I can see some logic in it, I wouldn't recommend teaching students usage that conflicts with what they will encounter elsewhere.

In English we might write "a function from a set $X$ to a set $T$, where $X\subseteq S$ " or  "a function on a set $X$ with values in a set $T$, where $X\subseteq S$ ". The abbreviated form  "a function from a set  $X\subseteq S$ to a set $T$ " would perhaps be considered acceptable by enough people, but the purely symbolic form $f : X ⊆ S → T$ is not normal. Viewed syntactically, the arrow points from the $S$ to the $T$. But $S$ has nothing to do with the function $f$; it just happens to be the case that $X\subseteq S$. The notation seems to conflate *function* with *partial function*.

I would edit the rest of the translated text to:

"The set $X$ is called the *definition set* or *domain* of the function $f$. The subset of $T$ comprising the values $f(x)$ ($x\in X$) is called the *value set* or *codomain* [sic] of $f$ and is denoted by $f(X)$."

Comment: Regarding faulty terminology: the wording "a function f of set X ⊆ S in T" is the literal translation from Italian, not an interpretation or an abbreviation of mine. I assume this remains correct Italian parlance. Idem for "values set": there the plural form is used.

Comment: @davide : See my added explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm also sensible to what you consider a faulty English translation. Could you clarify that?

Comment: @davide : I have added my version of your translation.

Comment: I think "The subset of T comprising the values" is wrong, as the word you chose, "comprising", ambiguously means "containing at least the values". Note that I made it explicit that the definition of codomain given by the textbook coincides with the contemporary one of image of a function.

Comment: @davide : In mathematical terminology, *comprising* the values does not admit anything other than the values; it does not mean merely *containing* the values. I agree that, in earlier, non-mathematical, English, some writers did use the term in that looser sense. The problem with *consisting of* the values is that, while it excludes non-values, arguably it doesn't necessarily include *all* the values. This is perhaps a rather pedantic point, and generally it would not be misunderstood if one used *consisting of* in this context.